# How would I write a Regular Expression to capture the value between Last Slash and Query String?

Tags: javascript, regex

**Problem:**

Extract image file name from CDN address similar to the following:

```
https://cdnstorage.api.com/v0/b/my-app.com/o/photo%2FB%_2.jpeg?alt=media&token=4e32-a1a2-c48e6c91a2ba
```

**Two-stage Solution:**

I am using two regular expressions to retrieve the file name:

```
var postLastSlashRegEx = /[^\/]+$/,
    preQueryRegEx = /^([^?]+)/;

var fileFromURL =  urlString.match(postLastSlashRegEx)[0].match(preQueryRegEx)[0];

// fileFromURL = "photo%2FB%_2.jpeg"
```

**Question:**

Is there a way I can combine both regular expressions?

I've tried using capture groups, but haven't been able to produce a working solution.

Comment: You could split the string at the `?` and then substring from the last `/` onwards. Why do in regex what a simple function could do?

Comment: How about a lookahead? [`/[^/]+(?=\?)/`](https://regex101.com/r/zdK1lM/1)

Comment: Just use `urlString.match(/[^?]*\/([^?]+)/)[1]`

Comment: @JosephMarikle: In that case, `?` must appear in the input. When using `?` in a negated character class, it does not have to be there.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Then you can just OR it with the end of the line indicator: `/[^/]+?(?=\?|$)/ `

Comment: Thanks for all your help @JosephMarikle and @WiktorStribiżew! You've both helped me solve this. Didn't think about using a lookahead.

Comment: And you do not need any lookahead here. Use my suggestion that involves the least overhead for a regex engine.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, that makes sense; lookaheads are "expensive".

Comment: @Lindauson: Well, lookaheads by themselves are OK, but lookarounds with alternation inside are better saved for more complex scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*From my comment*

You can use a lookahead to find the "?" and use `[^/]` to match any non-slash characters.

[`/[^/]+(?=\?)/`](https://regex101.com/r/zdK1lM/1)

To remove the dependency on the URL needing a "?", you can make the lookahead match a question mark or the end of line indicator (represented by `$`), but make sure the first glob is non-greedy.

[`/[^/]+?(?=\?|$)/`](https://regex101.com/r/sATQhY/1)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use regex, you can just use split and substr.

```
var str = "https://cdnstorage.api.com/v0/b/my-app.com/o/photo%2FB%_2.jpeg?alt=media&token=4e32-a1a2-c48e6c91a2ba".split("?")[0];
var fileName = temp.substr(temp.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

but if regex is important to you, then:

```
str.match(/[^?]*\/([^?]+)/)[1]
```

Comment: Please remove my regex from your answer if you do not understand what it does.

Answer (score 0):

The code using the substring method would look like the following -

`var fileFromURL = urlString.substring(urlString.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, urlString.lastIndexOf('?'))`

Comment: Thanks for your response, @Atty. I knew I could use string functions but I wanted to see what a pure regex solution would look like.